# How to delete the last div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, duplicates, innerhtml

This function duplicates my div.

How can I delete the last div?

```
function duplicate_it(myid,myform) { 
 var x = document.getElementById(myid).innerHTML;
 document.getElementById(myform).innerHTML += x; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not duplicating it. It is grabbing the innerHTML and addeding it to myForm.

If you want to delete something, add a counter and wrap it in a container:

```
cnt=0;
function duplicate_it(myid,myform) { 
  var x = document.getElementById(myid).innerHTML;
  document.getElementById(myform).innerHTML += '<div id="xx'+(cnt++)+'">'+x+'</div>';
}
```

now you can delete `document.getElementById("xx"+(cnt-1))`

A cleaner way is

```
cnt=0;
function duplicate_it(myid,myform) { 
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id="xx"+(cnt++);
  div.innerHTML = document.getElementById(myid).innerHTML;
  document.getElementById(myform).appendChild(div);
}
```